# Why does this activator text disappear when treating slot as scoped slot?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, activator

Vuetify's `v-list-group` activator text disappears when treating it as a scoped slot using the new Vue syntax (`<template v-slot:activator>` vs `<template v-slot:activator="{on}">`).

I forked the Vuetify example Codepen and stripped it down for simplicity. I have it set up so that I can easily comment the activator to use scoped slots or not. The activator text definitely shows when using just `v-slot:activator`.

Here is my Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Made-of-Clay/pen/rNBzeaQ&editors=101

The original pen that I forked from: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101 )

The docs page where I found the pen: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists#expansion-lists

I don't notice errors or warnings. I expect the activator text to show up when using `v-slot:activator="{on}"` and `v-on="on"` as the docs indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `="{on}"` on the end will change the slot usage from a normal slot to a scoped slot. I'm not sure why you think the `activator` slot for `v-list-group` can be used as a scoped slot, nothing I've found in the documentation suggests that it supports this.

If we take a look at the code for `v-list-group` we see this:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/db84347f242fe73288b72c7e72a1af04b09c9434/packages/vuetify/src/components/VList/VListGroup.ts#L157

`activator` is being accessed as a normal slot, via `this.$slots.activator`. This will only work if you use a normal slot.

Contrast that with other components, such as `v-menu`. The `v-menu` component also has an `activator` slot but it supports using it as either a normal slot or a scoped slot.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/db84347f242fe73288b72c7e72a1af04b09c9434/packages/vuetify/src/components/VMenu/VMenu.ts#L435

Note how this explicitly references both `this.$slots.activator` and `this.$scopedSlots.activator`. In this case the actual inclusion of this slot happens in the `activatable` mixin:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/db84347f242fe73288b72c7e72a1af04b09c9434/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/activatable/index.ts#L82

You'll notice that this does support an `on` value being passed to the scoped slot. There's a helper being used here called `getSlot` that smoothes over the differences between normal and scoped slots:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/db84347f242fe73288b72c7e72a1af04b09c9434/packages/vuetify/src/util/helpers.ts#L477

None of this applies to `v-list-group`, which just supports a normal slot.

Comment: I suppose I was expecting the slot to pass the `on` object like it does with `v-menu`, but that appears to not be the case. I added `v-tooltip` inside it to test my use case and everything is working. Thanks for straightening me out @skirtle !